# Drawing A Circle With Gradient Stroke

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, cagradientlayer

I am working on a task in which I must create a circle with no fill, but a gradient stroke.  For reference, here is the end result I am after;

[image: Circle with gradient stroke]

Given other occurrences with the app, I am drawing my circle like so;

```
let c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
c.saveGState()
let clipPath: CGPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: converted_rect, cornerRadius: converted_rect.width / 2).cgPath
c.addPath(clipPath)
c.setLineWidth(9.0)
c.setStrokeColor(UIColor.blue.cgColor)
c.closePath()
c.strokePath()
c.restoreGState()
let result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

This results in a  circle with a blue stroke.  Despite many searches around SO, I'm struggling to figure out how I'd replace that `setStrokeColor` with a gradient, rather than a blue color.  My most success came from creating a `CAGradientLayer`, then masking it with a `CAShapeLayer` created from the path, but I was only able to create a filled circle, not a hollow circle.

Thank you!

Comment: Would a gradient layer with an appropriate mask work in this instance?

Comment: @solenoid I tried that with limited success.  That got me to a filled circle with a gradient, but not a circle with a gradient stroke.

Comment: Have you reviewed [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+stroke+gradient)?

Comment: Well, the mask would be kind of 2 paths - one inside one outside

Comment: @rmaddy I have.  Where I can't seem to convert the logic is how to draw any sort of circle/gradient in context, rather than adding to a view's layer, which is impractical in my case.

Comment: https://medium.com/swift-programming/how-to-create-an-angle-gradient-border-in-swift-f4856dde4c90

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The basic idea is to use your path as a clipping path, then draw the gradient.

```
let c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
let clipPath: CGPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: converted_rect).cgPath

c.saveGState()
c.setLineWidth(9.0)
c.addPath(clipPath)
c.replacePathWithStrokedPath()
c.clip()

// Draw gradient
let colors = [UIColor.blue.cgColor, UIColor.red.cgColor]
let offsets = [ CGFloat(0.0), CGFloat(1.0) ]
let grad = CGGradient(colorsSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), colors: colors as CFArray, locations: offsets)
let start = converted_rect.origin
let end = CGPoint(x: converted_rect.maxX, y: converted_rect.maxY)
c.drawLinearGradient(grad!, start: start, end: end, options: [])

c.restoreGState()

let result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Setup a `CGGradient` first with the desired colors. Then for a linear gradient you use `drawLinearGradient`. For a radial gradient, use `drawRadialGradient`.

Comment: I have given this a try but it results in nothing actually being drawn.  How does the linear gradient understand that it has any correlation to the clip path?

Comment: It's all in how you setup the `CGGradient` and draw it with `drawLinearGradient` or `drawRadialGradient`.

Comment: Bingo, @rmaddy!  This worked perfectly.  Thank you for the complete answer, that exactly accomplished what I was after.  You rock!

Comment: Great answer! Helps me so much!